# Virtual keyboard for label

Tags: javascript, asp.net, virtual

I am using a JavaScript virtual keyboard for an ASP.NET TextBox. But using a TextBox gives an option to use even system keyboard. I am trying to use an ASP.NET label instead but its not working. Is there any way to make use of virtual keyboard strictly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your textbox read only.

This way your user can not type in, but the javascript from the virtual keyboard can write. This is not a very good lokking user interface thow.

### Using Javascript

Second trick is to use the the onkeypress and delete the key. You can add `window.event.keyCode=0` on the TextBox when the key is pressed and reset every user input.

```
onkeypress="window.event.keyCode=0;return false;"
```

Like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest2" 
  onkeypress="window.event.keyCode=0;return false;"></asp:TextBox>
```

### New Version

This is works on every browser. I tested on chrome,firefox,ie

```
<script>
function DisableKeyboardOnMe(e)
{   
    try
    {
        if (window && window.event)
            window.event.keyCode = 0;
        else
            e.which = 0;
    }
    catch(e){} 

    return false;
}   
</script>
```

and

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest3" 
    onkeypress="return DisableKeyboardOnMe(event);">test</asp:TextBox>
```

### One more simple way.

I tested on all my browsers and this is working also.

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest4" 
      onkeypress="return false;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: How to implement onkeypress? I used it in VB but cannot find it in ASP.NET using C#

Comment: @Kars this is javascript, you just add it as you see it inside the TextBox, or you add it by code behind as attribute.

Comment: I added in this manner `Password : <asp:TextBox ID="tbxt_passwrd" runat="server" Width="200" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off" onfocus="getFocus(this.id);" onkeypress="window.event.keyCode=0;"></asp:TextBox> ` but it is not working

Comment: @Kars I have update my answer, I tested and its work. Please vote and accept if you use it.

Comment: `Password : <asp:TextBox ID="tbxt_passwrd" runat="server" onkeypress="window.event.keyCode=0; return false;" Width="200" TextMode="Password" autocomplete="off" onfocus="getFocus(this.id);"></asp:TextBox> ` This is what I used but still not working

Comment: @Kars yes I see now is not working on firefox, works on ie, and chrome... I check now why...

Comment: @Aristos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1285/discussion-between-kars-and-aristos)